# SQL Query to do IN in multiple

Tags: sql

I have a query which returns me list of users and their group information. Like this

```
Select Username, UserId, ADUserGroup.Name as GroupName, SocialNumber as SSN, Grade

FROM 
ADUserGroup 
INNER JOIN ADUser ON ADUser.Id = UserId 
INNER JOIN ExpandedGroupInformation ON ExpandedGroupInformation.Name = ADUserGroup.Name 

WHERE ADUserGroup.Name IN (

SELECT substring(Name, 0, charindex('_Manager', Name)) as GroupName

--CASE WHEN UserId = (SELECT Id FROM ADUser WHERE Username = 'alf123teacher' ) then 1 else 0 end as Mine 

FROM ADUserGroup

--WHERE UserId = (SELECT Id FROM ADUser WHERE Username = 'alf123teacher') 

WHERE Name like 'ZZA%_Manager'

)
```

What I want is to check if the group is mine or not. For that I have to have this query like this

```
Select Username, UserId, ADUserGroup.Name as GroupName, SocialNumber as SSN, Grade

FROM 
ADUserGroup 
INNER JOIN ADUser ON ADUser.Id = UserId 
INNER JOIN ExpandedGroupInformation ON ExpandedGroupInformation.Name = ADUserGroup.Name 

WHERE ADUserGroup.Name IN (

SELECT substring(Name, 0, charindex('_Manager', Name)) as GroupName,

CASE WHEN UserId = (SELECT Id FROM ADUser WHERE Username = 'alf123teacher' ) then 1 else 0 end as Mine 

FROM ADUserGroup

--WHERE UserId = (SELECT Id FROM ADUser WHERE Username = 'alf123teacher') 

WHERE Name like 'ZZA%_Manager'

)
```

But then the issue is that I can't have IN operator because IN wants only one value list from the select. How can I do this?

Thanks

So the updated query is this

```
    SELECT Distinct u.Username, u.Id, ug.Name as GroupName, u.SocialNumber as SSN, Grade,

   (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM ADUser u2
                      WHERE u2.Username = 'alf123teacher'
                       AND
                            u2.Id = ugm.UserId
                     )
         THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END) as is_mine

FROM ADUserGroup as ug 

JOIN
 ADUser as u
 ON ug.UserId = u.Id

JOIN
 ExpandedGroupInformation as egi
 ON egi.Name = ug.Name 
JOIN

 (SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(ug2.Name, CHARINDEX('_Manager', ug2.Name) - 1) as new_name,
         ug2.UserId
  FROM ADUserGroup as ug2
  WHERE ug2.Name like 'ZZA%_Manager' 
 ) ugm

 ON ugm.new_name = ug.Name;
```

I had to add distinct. Now I the issue is the groups which are mine are coming twice. One with mine = 1 and one with mine = 0

[image]

Comment: Try `EXISTS` instead of `IN`.

Comment: I tried but couldn't construct it

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to transform the `IN` into a `JOIN`.  I think this is the logic:

```
SELECT u.Username, u.UserId, ug.Name as GroupName, u.SocialNumber as SSN, Grade,
       (CASE WHEN u2.UserId IS NOT NULL
                         )
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) as is_mine
FROM ADUserGroup ug JOIN
     ADUser u
     ON ADUser.Id = u.UserId JOIN
     ExpandedGroupInformation egi
     ON egi.Name = ug.Name JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(ug2.Name, CHARINDEX('_Manager', ug2.Name) - 1) as new_name,
             ug2.UserId
      FROM ADUserGroup ug2
      WHERE ug2.Name like 'ZZA%_Manager' 
     ) ugm
     ON ugm.new_name = ug.name;
```

EDIT:

You can handle the is mine in the subquery:

```
SELECT u.Username, u.UserId, ug.Name as GroupName, u.SocialNumber as SSN, Grade,
       ugm.is_mine
FROM ADUserGroup ug JOIN
     ADUser u
     ON ADUser.Id = u.UserId JOIN
     ExpandedGroupInformation egi
     ON egi.Name = ug.Name JOIN
     (SELECT LEFT(ug2.Name, CHARINDEX('_Manager', ug2.Name) - 1) as new_name,
             ug2.UserId, 1 as is_mine
      FROM ADUserGroup ug2 LEFT JOIN
           ADUser u2
           ON ug2.UserId = u2.UserId AND
              u2.Username = 'alf123teacher' 
      WHERE ug2.Name like 'ZZA%_Manager' 
     ) ugm
     ON ugm.new_name = ug.name;
```

Comment: I updated the query. Can you see the issue I am having. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @mohsinali1317 . . . Does the subquery return reasonable values?  Your version looks correct.

Comment: the issue is that I get duplicate values.

Comment: I added an image for you to see the record.

Comment: I think the duplicate is because of the is_mine case